# It is possible to play the .m3u8 file as AES-128 encryption in Chrome cast

Tags: chromecast

What steps i will reproduce the problem?

1. `http://.../video/tvn/viewnow/aesEnc/TVN55340HLS/TVN55340HLS.m3u8` this is my AES-128 encryption file is not casting?
2. In this url encryption key method as `#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://...:8080/KMServices/KeyManagerProxy?cmd=key&name=TVN55340HLS_1024x576_main_2400-K1`
3. I can casting the normal Hls file(with out AES-128) from same server.

What i expected output? What do you see instead? casting the AES-128 encryption in my application,but i get this Status `{statusCode=SERVICE_MISSING, resolution=null}` in sender side in android.

What version of the product i am using? On what operating system? 
android 4.4, recever.js is 2.0, media player lib is 1.0.0, windows xp, chrome cast firmware version: 27946. In receiver side url is Https but the HLS content host server is Http, it is must the SSL certificate as Content server for casting the AES-128 encryption file.

How to play the AES-128 encryp file in chrome cast?

Answer (score 0):

For AES-128 encryption, your stream has to be over https. For future reference, whenever you have issues with the receiver, you need to enable debugging on your receiver in the chrome debugger console and look at the console log to understand what is causing the issue.

Comment: the link "https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player" exposes, if you are implementing AES-128 encrypted HLS media streams, you must specify that the Media Player Library be sourced over HTTPS, even during testing.  1.I put the https in src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js"> need or no need. 2. i need to put https as content urs is http://MY-SERVER-IP/video/tvn/viewnow/aesEnc/TVN55340HLS/TVN55340HLS.m3u8"  ? casting this file here need the HTTPS OR NOT?